# Send multiple values with checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a form and this form contains this table:

```
<?php foreach($resultTable as $key => $value)
    {
    ?>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td><input type = "checkbox" name="idPriv[]" id="idPriv"  onclick="evaluateIT(this)" data-related-item="adminPanelShow" value ="<?php echo $value["id"]?>" />
                  <input name="rowID[]" id="rowID[]" class="adminPanel" hidden="hidden" type="text" value="<?php echo $value["id"]?>"/></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="userName[]" id="userName" class="adminPanel" value="<?php echo $value["userName"]?>"/></td>
              <td><input  name="firstName[]" type="text" id="firstName" class="adminPanel" value="<?php echo $value["firstName"]?>"/></td>
           </tr>
<?php } ?>

        </table>
```

When I'm selecting the wanted checkboxes and submitting the form, I want to use **only** the checkboxes that I checked. That means, the `idPriv[]` array returns only the checkboxes that was pressed, **BUT** the other arrays (`userName[], firstName[]`) send all of the data **for all the rows.**

How do I extract the data from those arrays only (and disregard the rows that wasn't checked)?

Comment: `name="userName[<?=$value["id"]?>]"`

Comment: Your markup is failing. Fix it.  (your are opening but not closing the tables, and why are you opening new tables all the time?.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the checkboxes are checked, parse them as such:

```
foreach($resultTable as $key => $value)
{
    if($value==="on")
    {
        // checked checkbox has a value of "on"
        // triple = sign means value is exactly "on"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect each `userName`, `firstName` field with checkbox value:

```
foreach($resultTable as $key => $value)
{?>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td><input type = "checkbox" name="idPriv[]" id="idPriv"  onclick="evaluateIT(this)" data-related-item="adminPanelShow" value ="<?php echo $value["id"]?>" />
              <input name="rowID[]" id="rowID[]" class="adminPanel" hidden="hidden" type="text" value="<?php echo $value["id"]?>"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="userName[<?php echo $value["id"]?>]" id="userName" class="adminPanel" value="<?php echo $value["userName"]?>"/></td>
                                                 ^--- here
          <td><input  name="firstName[<?php echo $value["id"]?>]" type="text" id="firstName" class="adminPanel" value="<?php echo $value["firstName"]?>"/></td>
                                       ^--- here
       </tr>
}
</table>
```

After that in your script you can do something like that:

```
foreach ($_POST[`idPriv`] as $id) {
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'][$id];
    $userName = $_POST['userName'][$id];
    // ...
}
```